# React Use RouteComponentProps - Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I am using React with Typescript and needs to use the history for that I need to have interface of RouteComponentProps

```
export default class Routes extends Component<RouteComponentProps, any> {
  render() {
   return (
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
 }}
```

When I use the props interface as RouteComponentProps it gives me error at below code.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
     <Provider>
       <React.Fragment>
         <Navbar />
         <Routes />
       </React.Fragment>
     </Provider>
 );
}
}
```

Error comes when I try to use my Route Component. The error says

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly>': history, location, match  TS2739

Kindly help in resolving this issue

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you have to pass these props to your component.

ofc you dont want to pass it in App component. Just wrap it with [hoc](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) from react-router lib)

high order component "withRouter" will do the job

```
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';    
class Routes extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps, any> {

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Routes);
```